# Como editar el "PlaceHolder" del input type date

Tags: css, html5

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente como tal tengo un formulario que maneja diferentes campos, entre ellos campos tipo fechas, el cual tiene como un "`PlaceHolder`" automático de el formato de fecha, el problema es que tengo editados mis estilos de `input` y como tal que se vea ese formato de fecha perjudica el `UI` se ve de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven se sobre pone sobre mi edición del `input` lo que quiero lograr es quitar ese formato de fecha que se ve, este es mi código.

HTML:

```html
<div class='estiloDate' id='datetimepicker1'>
 <input type='date' class="question" name="name" id="fechaNacimiento" required autocomplete="off"/>
 <label for="fechaNacimiento"><span>Fecha de nacimiento </span></label>
</div>
```

Código CSS que se le aplica a los `input`:

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
 input[type=password]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{ 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }

input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{
    margin-right: -300px;
}


/*
Basic input element using psuedo classes
*/
h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

input,
span,
label,
textarea,
select{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus,
select:focus {
  outline: 0;
  /*padding: 2px;*/
}
/* Question */

input.question,
textarea.question,
select.question{
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: padding-top 0.2s ease, margin-top 0.2s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hack to make "rows" attribute apply in Firefox. */
}

/* Underline and Placeholder */

input.question + label,
textarea.question + label,
select.question + label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  height: 0px;
}

input.question:focus + label,
textarea.question:focus + label,
select.question:focus + label {
  width: 100%;
}

input.question:focus,
input.question:valid {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
select.question:focus,
select.question:valid {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

textarea.question:valid,
textarea.question:focus {
  margin-top: 10px;
}



input.question:focus + label > span,
input.question:valid + label > span {
  top: -50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
}
select.question:focus + label > span,
select.question:valid + label > span {
  top: -50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
}

textarea.question:focus + label > span,
textarea.question:valid + label > span {
  top: -50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
}

input.question:valid + label,
textarea.question:valid + label,
select.question:valid +label{
  border-color: green;
}

input.question:invalid,
textarea.question:invalid,
select.question:invalid{
  box-shadow: none;
}

input.question + label > span,
textarea.question + label > span,
 select.question + label > span{
    display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #8F8F8F;
  font-size: 100%;
  top: -22px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, font-size 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, font-size 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Agregar esto al final de tu CSS**

> Para Chrome:

```
input[type=date]:required:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: transparent;
}
```

> Para Firefox

```
input[type=date] { color: transparent !important; } 
.active input[type=date] { color: inherit !important; }
```